# evaluate a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

When I try to calculate the characteristic function of a probability distribution, I encounter a series.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\left(\left(\frac{a\lambda}{1+a\lambda}\right)^k\cdot\frac{(1+a)(1+2a)\cdots(1+(k-1)a)}{a^k\cdot k!}\right)}$$

What is the result of this series?

Comment: Which probability distribution is this? I'm asking because if we knew an expression for the characteristic function, we could let people work backwards. Whatever you're informing me of, make sure to put it in the question, this is in line with improving your question and making it easier to answer.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles. Also, you don't "solve" a series; rather, you "find" or "evaluate" it.

Comment: Have a look at the power series expansion of $(1 - z)^{-1 - 1/a}$.

Comment: You didn't read the advice on why your question was closed, so editing it will not help you. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and fix these issues properly this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 \sum\limits_{1 \le k} {\left( {\frac{{a\lambda }}{{1 + a\lambda }}} \right)^{\,k} \frac{{\left( {1 + a} \right)
\left( {1 + 2a} \right) \cdots \left( {1 + \left( {k - 1} \right)a} \right)}}{{a^{\,k} k!}}}  =  \\ 
  = \sum\limits_{1 \le k} {\left( {\frac{{a\lambda }}{{1 + a\lambda }}} \right)^{\,k} \frac{{a^{\,k - 1} 
 \left( {1/a + 1} \right)\left( {1/a + 2} \right) \cdots \left( {1/a + \left( {k - 1} \right)} \right)}}{{a^{\,k} k!}}}  =  \\ 
  = \sum\limits_{1 \le k} {\left( {\frac{{a\lambda }}{{1 + a\lambda }}} \right)^{\,k} \frac{{1/a\left( {1/a + 1} \right)
\left( {1/a + 2} \right) \cdots \left( {1/a + \left( {k - 1} \right)} \right)}}{{k!}}}  =  \\ 
  = \sum\limits_{1 \le k} {\left( {\frac{{a\lambda }}{{1 + a\lambda }}} \right)^{\,k}
 \frac{{\left( {1/a} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } }}{{k!}}} 
 = \sum\limits_{1 \le k} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \left( {\frac{{a\lambda }}{{1 + a\lambda }}} \right)^{\,k}
 \frac{{\left( { - 1/a} \right)^{\underline {\,k\,} } }}{{k!}}}  =  \\ 
  = \sum\limits_{1 \le k} {\left( \begin{array}{c}  - 1/a \\  k \\ 
 \end{array} \right)\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \left( {\frac{{a\lambda }}{{1 + a\lambda }}} \right)^{\,k} }
  =  - 1 + \left( {1 - \frac{{a\lambda }}{{1 + a\lambda }}} \right)^{\, - 1/a}  =  \\ 
  = \left( {1 + a\lambda } \right)^{\,1/a}  - 1\quad \left| {\;\left| {\frac{{a\lambda }}{{1 + a\lambda }}}
 \right| < 1} \right. \\ 
 \end{array}
$$

where $x^{\,\underline {\,k\,} } ,\quad x^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } $ represent respectively the [Falling and Rising Factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)